# Custom pagination in laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel

I want to be able to edit the pagination, but I've googled this online and everything hasn't worked at all.

```
<div class="pagination">
   {{ $servers->links() }}
</div>
```

I added it so that I have the pagination in my `resources/views/vendors/pagination` but editing the style there hasn't worked there as  well.

How would you be able to edit the pagination background color and text color?

Answer (score 1):

You need to publish default pagination views (templates) to be able to edit it.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

The default pagination view will be in file `resources/views/vendor/pagination/bootstrap-4.blade.php`. There you can edit whatever you want. You want to edit background but you did not specify if/what CSS framework are you using, but I assume that it is bootstrap 4 then just add for example class "bg-secondary" on element you need.

If you are using another framework or simply do not wanna use build-in paginator template then you can simply make new paginator template.

More in docs: [Customizing The Pagination View](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view)